# OnLoad Click or Trigger embed lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I get on one of my pages I want an lightbox to be loaded. I cant figure out how to make it happen.

Part of the jQuery:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery.js"></script>
<script src='http://fliphtml5.com/plugin/LightBox/js/fliphtml5-light-box-api-min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".foo").trigger('click'); 
});
</script>
</head>
```

The image/link that should be clicked automaticly:

```
<img class="foo" src="imgs/logo-growpact.png"data-rel='fh5-light-box-demo' data-href='http://online.fliphtml5.com/classified' data-width='1280' data-height='720' data-title='Rootcage'>
```

Comment: i this line $(".foo").trigger('click'); 
<script
});

Comment: `('click');});</script>` should be like this at the end

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
$(".foo").trigger('click'); 
});
</script>`

Comment: Fixed it all but still doesntt work

Comment: The `<img>` tag ends with `</a>`? Another typo?

Comment: @ShaunakD The lightbox works i know that and that </a> doesnt matter either but yea its not my own code but i need to fix it but i need to let the lightbox pop up when i load the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Just remove your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery.js"></script>
```

And try this :

```
<html>

   <head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script src='http://fliphtml5.com/plugin/LightBox/js/fliphtml5-light-box-api-min.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <script>
   jQuery(function(){

        jQuery('.foo').click();


});
   </script>
     <img class="foo" src="imgs/logo-growpact.png" data-rel='fh5-light-box-demo' data-href='http://online.fliphtml5.com/classified' data-width='1280' data-height='720' data-title='Rootcage'>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the Fiddle: [CHECK THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/3kSCL/1/)

**UPDATED**

```
<script>
  jQuery(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('.foo').click();
        },400);

    });
   </script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3kSCL/2/)

Comment: Well my slideshow wont work if i remove that ;) i need the frame to be loaded when i load the page i know it works but i just need it to load when i come on the page

Comment: can u add a fiddle something like - [THAT](http://jsfiddle.net/3kSCL/)?

Comment: The fiddle you made is right but i need that frame which opens when you click the "broken image atm" i need that to open instantly when i load the page. so like if you click the page/fiddle or what ever it first opens the lightbox

Comment: I need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/fc6Yk/ but then with my lightbox instead of the alert

Comment: @Shikez - check my updated answer and i also added Fiddle.. please check.. hope this time it works

Comment: The fiddle is exactly what i need but i cant manage to make it work on my site D: http://www.visser.eu/supplies/rootcage

Comment: add some delay time.. Check Updated Answer.

Comment: You my friend made my day haha I can lunch in peace now

Comment: Glad... it works.. and enjoy your lunch.